find the column number in typst
I'd like to get the column number of a heading in typst. I have a two column layout and want to shift headings toward the outside of the page.
If it was page instead of column, I would be able to do counter(page), but there isn't the equivalent for counter(column).
#show heading.where(level: 1): it => {
  let col = counter(column).at(it.location()).first() // this doesn't work
  let shift = 0.5in
  if col == 1 {
    shift *= -1
  }
  move(dx: shift, it.body)
}

One messy option is to figure it out based on the current position on the page:
// pull header into the outside margin a bit
#show heading.where(level: 1): it => {
  let pos = it.location().position()
  let shift = 0.5in
  if page.margin.inside.length + pos.x < page.width/2 { // left column
    shift *= -1
  }
  move(dx: shift, it.body)
}

but it would be cleaner to just know which column it is in.
